# Logo doesn't appear normally to some users

Tags: 2010, 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, permissions

There is normal version which shows mostly to all users:

[image: Normal version]

There is error version which shows currently to 2 users:

[image]

Worth to mention that those 2 users have `read permission` on homepage, somewhere don't have Access at all and somewhere Design, while other mostly have `edit/Design permissions`.

How do I fix this? Can't find solutions.

Comment: Could it be that these 2 mentioned users don't have access to the folder which onctains the site logo?

Comment: Thanks, helped me. Really simple sollution! Much appreciated.

Comment: Moe could you please add this as answer so that other can get benefit from it.

Answer (score 2):

As it was already resolved in the comments:

> Could it be that these 2 mentioned users don't have access to the folder which contains the site logo?

As a side note: Usually this kind of cases where site has multiple permission levels for users and some expected behavior can't be reached at some user levels, it indeed is about the permissions :)